# Bootstrap Carousel Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to implement the Bootstrap 3 carousel and am having some issues.  When selecting next, the transition does not occur.  I have tried working through all of the answers on this topic here, but have not had success.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my current code:

```
    <head>
    ...
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-1.12.3.js">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </head>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="images/slide-1-splash.png" alt="splash" class = "img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="images/slide-2-interests.png" alt="interests" class = "img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="images/slide-3-people.png" alt="people" class = "img-responsive">
                </div> 
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="images/slide-4-messages.png" alt="messages" class = "img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've forgot to include `bootstrap.js` in your project. Since the carousel is using some javascript code you just need to implement the file.

I've just copied your code into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yj3oL4f2/) and also included the `bootstrap.js` file and it started working.

I've also noticed, you're using wrong including for your javascript file. Except of this, you've not included `bootstrap.css` file. Try using this (you can change the source through your own, local ones, if you want to):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I added 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap.js"> 

in the header, but it still didn't seem to work.  Does order of arrangement matter? Any further suggestions?

Comment: You've got any errors in your console? Do you have the exact same code in your code as I've used in my fiddle? Maybe you could share a own fiddle with your code sample? Could help a lot.

Comment: Nope, no errors in the console.  I tested with the same code as you featured in your own fiddle, and it's still behaving the same way.  How are you implementing the bootstrap.js file in the header?

Comment: Sorry, noticed that too late. You're using wrong including for your files. Check my edited answer, this should solve the problem. You also may google around for some tutorials on how to include css and js files into your project. Let me know if that helps.